# how do i send a timestamped image name to mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Below I have included my code that uploads multiple images to a folder and the path to mysql. I am brand new so please excuse me for such a silly question but I can not figure where to start with sending this timestamp or $fileName value to mysql.

```
<?php
require_once('storescripts/connect.php');
mysql_select_db($database_phpimage,$phpimage);
$uploadDir = 'upload/';

if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{


foreach ($_FILES as $file)
{

    $fileName = $file['name'];
    $tmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $file['size'];
    $fileType = $file['type'];

    if ($fileName != ""){
        $filePath = $uploadDir;
        $fileName = str_replace(" ", "_", $fileName);

        //Split the name into the base name and extension
        $pathInfo = pathinfo($fileName);
        $fileName_base = $pathInfo['fileName'];
        $fileName_ext = $pathInfo['extension'];

        //now we re-assemble the file name, sticking the output of uniqid into it
        //and keep doing this in a loop until we generate a name that 
        //does not already exist (most likely we will get that first try)
        do {
           $fileName = $fileName_base . uniqid() . '.' . $fileName_ext;
        } while (file_exists($filePath.$fileName));

        $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath.$fileName);
    }


if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$fileName = addslashes($fileName);
$filePath = addslashes($filePath);
}
$fileinsert[]=$filePath;
}
    $cat=$_POST['cat'];//this is the category the product is stored in
    $about=$_POST['about'];//this is some general information about the item
    $price=$_POST['price'];//the price of the item
    $item=$_POST['item'];//the name of the item
    $name1=basename($_FILES['image01'][$fileName]);//the file name of the first actual jpg
    $name2=basename($_FILES['image02'][$fileName]);//the file name of the sencond actual jpg
    $name3=basename($_FILES['image03'][$fileName]);//the file name of the third actual jpg
    $name4=basename($_FILES['image04'][$fileName]);//the file name of the fourth actual jpg

$query = "INSERT INTO image (mid, cid, about, price, item, name1, name2, name3, name4) ".
"VALUES ('','$cat','$about','$price','$item','$name1','$name2','$name3','$name4')";

mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed : ' . mysql_error()); }


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to change:

```
$fileinsert[]=$filePath;
```

to:

```
$fileinsert = array();    // initialize the variable before the loop

...
$fileinsert[]=$filePath.$fileName;    // or just $fileName if you don't need the path in the DB
```

and then you need to change:

```
$name1=basename($_FILES['image01'][$fileName]);//the file name of the first actual jpg
$name2=basename($_FILES['image02'][$fileName]);//the file name of the sencond actual jpg
$name3=basename($_FILES['image03'][$fileName]);//the file name of the third actual jpg
$name4=basename($_FILES['image04'][$fileName]);//the file name of the fourth actual jpg
```

to:

```
$name1=$fileinsert[0];
$name2=$fileinsert[1];
$name3=$fileinsert[2];
$name4=$fileinsert[3];
```

Something like that should do it.

Comment: gladly. is that clicking on the star?

Comment: @userX No, it's a checkmark next to the top left of my answer, below the vote score.

Comment: got it thank you so much for all your help. i have learned greatly in these last 2 days, although now i have to reformat my queries to meet 3nf requirements!